# How to post data using requests module to a flask application?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, python-requests

I am trying to develop a small tiny application using flask and requests module. I tried to post some data to a flask web application. But I stuck at this error.

flask.py

```
@app.route('/add/', methods=['POST'])
def add_paths():
    paths = request.form['paths']
    tags = 'others'
    for path in paths:
        g.db.execute('insert into entries (path, tags) values(?, ?)',
            [path, tags])
        g.db.commit()
    message = 'New paths are posted'
    return jsonify(result = message)
```

command line file for posting the data

```
import json
import glob2
import requests

list = glob2.glob('/home/sheeshmohsin/*/**')
post_data = {'paths' : list }
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
post_response = requests.post(url='http://localhost:9696/add/', data=json.dumps(post_data), headers=headers)
print post_response
print post_response.text
```

And the error i am getting is:-

```
File "commandline.py", line 8, in <module>
    post_response = requests.post(url='http://127.0.0.1:9696/add/', data=json.dumps(post_data), headers=headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 88, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 335, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 438, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 327, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=9696): Max retries exceeded with url: /add/ (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

Comment: Are you sure your `flask.py` is listening on port 9696?  You have something like `app.run(port=9696)` and it says `* Running on http://127.0.0.1:9696/`?

Comment: yes, i have done that.

Comment: This is the link of flask.py, you can look at the file.
http://ur1.ca/i3otg

Comment: You still need to isolate the problem, have you tried using a browser to get to your flask instance?

Comment: through browser, its working fine

Answer (score 0):

The connection refused error message indicates it could be your firewall, or loopback:

- Check that firewall isn't blocking port 9696.
- I've had the loopback (127.0.0.1) cause similar issues, so replace `localhost` by actual IP address so that Python doesn't use loopback interface (`requests.post(url='http://localhost:9696/add/',...`). You might have to do same with Flask (`app..run(host='192.168...', port=9696)`).